# How to make a public repository private

Tags: git, command-line, command-line-interface, bonobo

How to make a public repository private via Command Line or in Bonobo Git
Thanks...
I've created a repository in BonoboGit, I want to make it private, how to?

Answer (score 0):

Git clients are only able to push and pull from remote repositories. Whether those remote repositories are public or private completely depends on the service that is hosting the repositories. Your best bet is to look for a command-line tool released by your git hosting service, or use their web interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that depends on the repo you are using. GitHub provides an API to do so. https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create.